# deleting all records for all tables in memory in Kdb+

Tags: kdb

I would like to delete all records for all tables in memory but still keep the schemas.

for example:

```
a:([]a:1 2;b:2 4);
b:([]c:2 3;d:3 5);
```

I wrote a function:

```
{[t] t::select from t where i = -1} each tables[]
```

this didnt work, so i tried

```
{[t] ![`t;enlist(=;`i;-1);0b;()]} each tables[]
```

didnt work either.
Any idea or better ways?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a global table name as a symbol, it removes all the rows, leaving an empty table

```
q)delete from `a
`a

q)a
a b
---

q)meta a
c| t f a
-| -----
a| j    
b| j
```

To do it for all global tables in root name space

```
{delete from x} each tables[]
```

Your second attempt using function was close. You can achieve it via the following (functional form of the above):

```
![;();0b;`symbol$()] each tables[]
```

- The first argument should be the symbol of the table for the same reason I mentioned before
- The second argument should be an empty list as we want to delete all records (we do not want to delete where i=-1, as that would delete nothing)
- The final argument (list of columns to delete) should be an empty symbol list instead of an empty general list.

Comment: thanks! any idea why I couldn't put t for the first arguement for function form?

Comment: Ignoring the issues with the final parameter which has been explained, you cannot pass a variable as a symbol if it is only defined locally as functional form expects it to be global. In your example above, `t` is only defined within the function so fails. If you removed the backtick and passed in the symbol of the globally defined table instead it would work

Comment: ok, how about this one then?{[t] t::select from t where i = -1} each tables[]

Comment: The variable `t` you are trying to set exists as a local variable. This updates the local variable but results in not setting the variable globally. You can see it has updated locally by returning the variable `{[t] t::select from t where i = -1;t}`. Change the `t::` to one that isn't defined locally e.g `t2::` to set it globally

Comment: Thank you Mark, but from {[t] t::select from t where i = -1;t} , where did i set t as local variable? I am just trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Mark's solution is best for doing what you want rather than functional form. Just adding to your question on t failing as putting kdb code in comments is awkward.

Your functional form fails not because of the `t` but because your last argument is not a symbol list `` `$() ``. Also you would want to delete where `i` is `> -1`, not `=`

```
q){[t] ![t;enlist(>;`i;-1);0b;`$()]} each `d`t`q
`d`t`q

q)d
date sym time bid1 bsize1 bid2 bsize2 bid3 bsize3 ask1 asize1 ask2 asize2 ask..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
q)t
date sym time src price size
----------------------------
q)q
date sym time src bid ask bsize asize
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks! why do we put symbol list for last argument?

Comment: The 4th argument in functional delete is a symbol list so therefore when deleting rows it should be an empty symbol list. For example functional delete of a column sym rather than rows would be:

````![t;();0b;enlist `sym]````

Comment: Thank you for the explaination!